# Concurrent map with a slice in golang

Tags: go, concurrency

I've been trying to sort out a concurrency problem after one of the devs working in this area left a couple of months ago but I'm lost on an appropriate way to solve this.

For context, we load a customers data into a structure like:

`[ Key ] -> { Value }`

`[customer-specific-hash] -> {Slice of data points/files}`

Example - really badly formatted sorry:

```
[a60d849ad97bfb833e1096941] 
-> 
{ 
 { StartDate: '01-02-2022', EndDate: '28-02-2022', DataFrames: [1598,921578,12981,21749,192578...]},
 { StartDate: '01-03-2022', EndDate: '28-03-2022', DataFrames: [1234,1567,6781,126978...]},
}
```

The above is because we have 100,000's of customers and there is a process that kicks off every night that consolidates there data based on the hashes (or a bucket really) per customer. Before processing the data frames, we go through the slice and "merge" the dataframes into a big DataFrame with lots of legal/accounting rules around it.

This runs within goroutines to index all the datapoints as fast as possible.

So the implementation is essentially a `sync.Map[string, []DataFrame]` but I noticed whilst the map operations are guarded, the appending to the dataframe slices is not. There could be about 20-30 file references in that slice every night for each hash.

There is every chance that the past 2 years, customer data would have been incorrectly merged & I've been tasked to fix it. Pre sync.map they had used a RWMutex with a Map - again, but not the slice and it points to [this article](https://medium.com/@deckarep/the-new-kid-in-town-gos-sync-map-de24a6bf7c2c) as a guide.

Firstly, is the idea of a Map that contains a slice the appropriate data structure?

I've tried to create a RWMutex based slice handler but wondered if the Map could have a `chan DataFrame` instead to throw  into when indexing a customers files, then once done, the second step of consolidating it into an array (as the `len(chanx)`) would be known instead?

I am coming from primarily Java, so I may have some terms confused so I apolgise.

Comment: Looks like Burak Sendar has graced you with a great answer.  He's one of the pros around here.   If you want to up your Go concurrency game, read https://go.dev/blog/codelab-share "don't communicate by sharing state; share state by communicating" (the channel based approach).  I try to avoid locks whenever possible; they're tricky to get right and omissions like this are all to easy.

Comment: thank-you @erik258 that's a great share and so succint in explanation :D I did wonder whether a channel approach would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate problems:

1. Concurrency issues while updating the map
2. Concurrency issues while updating an entry of the map

`sync.Map` will protect against 1, but not 2.

One way to deal with this problem is to have:

```
sync.Map[string, *DFrame]
```

where

```
type DFrame struct {
  sync.RWMutex 
  Data []DataFrame
}
```

Once to get an entry from the map, you should `Lock` or `RLock` it, and then work with the data. This is not just limited to the appending of the slice. You have to `RLock` the struct even if you are only reading from the data frames.

So if you are appending a new dataframe:

```
df := &DFrame{}
entry,_:=m.LoadOrStore(key, df)
dfEntry:=entry.(*DFrame)
dfEntry.Lock()
dfEntry.Data=append(dfEntry.Data, newDataFrame)
dfEntry.Unlock()
```

Comment: You've nailed my problem with both 1 & 2! and I was contemplating that same approach , except where do I append to the array in the above? Because in the first attempt to add to the map, i'd set `df.Data = []DataFrame{cdf}` on say line 3 (after the first lock), then if I already have an entry, inside my if condition I'd do the append the `entry.Data = append(entry.Data, cdf)`? Also why do you lock gain?

Comment: You can actually do without it. See edited answer.

Comment: Oh very clever, but may I ask why df.Unlock in the last  line vs dfEntry.Unlock? is that a typo or am I not understanding this?

Comment: That was a typo, sorry.

Comment: That is fantastic, I think I finally understand it and not the complex way I was about to go through it! T hank-you so much. Now the hard part comes (not me thankfully) of the company explaining the "irregularities" to the customers!

Comment: Im been reading deeper to get a better understanding of this and have a follow up question... Right now all the work for indexing dataframes with the Map happens in a bunch of goroutines that has a waitgroup. once out of the wait group it's synchronously iterated through each KEY (Hash) and the numbers from the  dataframes computed and sumarised and some other logic I dont understand... Does that bit  need to use an RLock/RUnlock here? There are no other writers, it's all readonly from this point.

Comment: If there are no writers after `waitgroup.Wait`, then there is no need to lock.  `Wait` establishes a happened-before relationship between reads that happen after the writes.